# Video short of woman re-living life with her husband who is in reality dead or on life support

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched a Sci fi short on YouTube a few years ago. (I thought it was from DUST but I think I'm wrong.)

It opens with a couple just living their life. Woman realizes stuff is repeating.

You don't find out until the very end of the short that her husband is dead or on life support. (I can't remember.) When she wakes up sitting in a doctor's office. The doctor is telling her she can't do it much longer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is the husband present when she wakes up (i.e. she wakes in a hospital room) or is he off-screen (she's in a consulting room)?  Why can't she do it any more?

Comment: He's not present when she comes to. I think she is in a consulting room, sitting not laying down. And I can't remember exactly why she couldn't do it anymore. I watched this in probably 2018? 2019? I just wanted to watch it again and I've been having a hard time finding it

Comment: Hmm. I recall something similar, where the twist is that the guy (a firefighter) is actually a memory record and his daughter is logging in to spend time with him. It was a crap pastiche  of Ghostbusters themes: https://www.firstshowing.net/2021/watch-short-film-deadlock-where-they-keep-spirits-of-the-dead/